# Enable C++11 support in VS 2013 from cmake

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I have this small `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/Qstd=c++11")

add_executable(demo src/main.cpp)
```

As far as I know the flag `/Qstd=c++11` should enable the support for C++11 when using `msvc++` but it doesn't, not even `/Qstd=c++0x` works.

What I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: Those flags are for Intel's C++ compiler, I believe.

Comment: @DrewDormann oh, I see, my bad, and how to do this with msvc++ ?

Comment: I don't think MSVC++ has a flag, I think it's _always_ in C++11 mode, unless you give it a ".c" file.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx

Comment: @MooingDuck what if I would like to set it for c++03 code ? The lack of support for a flag like that isn't really a good thing.

Comment: @user3784961 Welcome to MSVC :)

Comment: @Qix seriously ? I'm supposed to get an "heuristic guess" for which version of C++ I'm using ?

Comment: @user3784961: No, there is no guessing beyond what I said.  MSVC will _always_ use C++11 mode, unless given a C file, in which case it will _always_ use C90 mode.

Comment: @MooingDuck no, there isn't, but I'm trying to communicate with the compiler that I'm using and this implies that I don't have any idea how to set a specific version for my c++ codebase; it's an horrible idea in general.

Comment: @user3784961 That's how MSVC works. Each compiler version has a specifically implemented version of the C++ standard that cannot be changed. It is part of the reason why [Boost](http://www.boost.org) is still relevant even though a lot of its core features are now in the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS2013 supports c++11 without any additional flags.  You don't need to do anything extra (of course remember to use /EHsc to enable exception handling).

Answer (score 1):

As I can't comment, the closest you'll get to setting a non-C++11 compliant level with MSVC is by setting the platform toolkit to v100 (VS2010) as that'll put it back to a version where C++11 wasn't supported (at all I believe, but not entirely sure) But you'll also need the VS2010 compiler installed as well than.

Comment: what's the flag for that ?

Comment: Not a flag, its under Project Configuration > General > Platform toolset.

Comment: Also, VC10 (VS2010) had some C++11 stuff.  For C++03 you want VC9 (VS2009).

Comment: @user3784961: Basically what it is is simply using an old version of the compiler, from before C++11 was announced.  It's a different _binary_.