# missing ';' before 'boost::interprocess::offset_t' and missing type specifier - int assumed (boost 1.74.0, Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I have an issue compiling code for a c++ project using the boost library. Everything works as expected with Visual Studio 2019, however, I also need this to work with Visual Studio 2013 in another branch of the same product.

Here's an example header (redacted):

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/interprocess/managed_windows_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_condition.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <boost/container/scoped_allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/find.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include <REDACTED.h>
#include <REDACTED2.h>

static constexpr boost::interprocess::offset_t SHARED_MEMORY_SIZE_IN_BYTES = 300000;
```

Compiling this in visual studio 2019 works without problems. But with 2013, I get the following:

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'boost::interprocess::offset_t'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Can someone explain to be what could go wrong in this case? Is boost incompatible with vs13? It is a header-only library, so I've simply used the same header files in both 2019 and 2013 versions of the product.

Another stack overflow question: [Boost includes wreaks havoc - but it's not Boost's fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947409/boost-includes-wreaks-havoc-but-its-not-boosts-fault) mentions that the order of the headers might be at fault, so I tried moving about my REDACTED.h and REDACTED2.h, but the error still occurs.

Another question: [Building boost with Visual Studio 2013 (Express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813138/building-boost-with-visual-studio-2013-express) mentions  that there's been bugs in boost 1.55 related to visual studio 2013, but that they should be fixed. I assume 1.74.0 should include such fixes, but perhaps I need to apply some patch to 1.74.0 headers too, to get this working?

Comment: Are you sure Visual Studio 2013 supports C++11? The issue seems to be with `constexpr` rather than `boost`.

Comment: This is something I've noticed being mentioned in other stack overflow posts as well, it's quite possible that it does not support it. What is the correct approach then if I want to use boost 1.74.0 with VS13, if we assume c++11 is not supported by vs13? This thread mentions that it should be supported without additional flags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462371/enable-c11-support-in-vs-2013-from-cmake/24462976

Comment: Not sure what are the Boost requirements for C++ standard, but I'd first change `constexpr` to `const` and see if the compiler error is gone. If yes, the issue is not with Boost, but with the support of C++11 (perhaps it's enough to set flag `/std:c++11` or whatever was the flag in VS).

Comment: Thanks everyone for your quick help, this did indeed solve the problem!

Comment: I'm quite sure that Visual Studio 2013 supports only a part of C++11 (because I still use it for daily business). ;-)